# Create unit tests for a factory method

Tags: java, junit

I am following an older Java tutorial that is teaching the concept of the Service layer, my program is a very simple program that will create a list of Bills and their due dates. Where I am stuck is in creating the JUnit Test for factory methods.

First here is the Bill Constructor

```
public Bill(String bname, Double bamount, Date bdate, String bfrequency){
 this.billName = bname;
 this.billAmount = bamount;
 this.billDueDate = bdate;
 this.frequency = bfrequency;
}
```

Next is the Interface to save and get these bills

```
public interface IBill {
    public void save(Bill bill);
    public Bill read(Bill readbill);


}
```

Bear with me, next is the concrete implementation of the interface which are stubbed out for now, nothing implemented yet

```
public class BillSvcImpl implements IBill {

    @Override
    public void save(Bill bill) {
        System.out.println("Entering the Store BillInfo method");

    }

    @Override
    public Bill read(Bill readbill) {
        System.out.println("Entering the Read BillInfo method");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then there is the factory method that will create/call the concrete implementation

```
public class Factory {

    public IBill getBillInfo(){
        return new BillSvcImpl();
    }
```

}

Then finally the JUnit test where I am stucked

```
    public class BillSvcTest extends TestCase {
    private Factory factory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        factory = new Factory();

    }
    @test
    public void testSaveBill(){
        IBill bill = factory.getBillInfo();
        Bill nanny = new Bill("Nanny",128d,new Date(6/28/2013),"Montly");
        bill.save(nanny);
        //what goes here??, Assert??

    }

    @test
    public void testReadBill(){
    //How can I write a Test for this??
        //Please help
    }

}
```

The instruction is

> > Create a JUnit Test for your service, The test should use the Factory to get the service, instantiated in the setUp() method.

My service/interface have two methods save and get, how can I create a test for these before I start the actual implementation.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO `save` method should return something to say whether `Bill` got saved or not. I would have kept save method like this

```
public boolean save(Bill bill) {
    System.out.println("Entering the Store BillInfo method");
    boolean result = false;
    try {
       //..... saving logic
       result = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        result = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and did an assert in the testcase as

```
@Test
public void testSaveBill(){
    //Success
    IBill bill = factory.getBillInfo();
    Bill nanny = new Bill("Nanny",128d,new Date(6/28/2013),"Montly");
    assertTrue(bill.save(nanny));

   //Failure
   assertFalse(bill.save(null));
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help @sanbhat, your help worked for the saving, the same method did not work for testing my read method.

Comment: If you want the test to fail because an exception is thrown, you can check for that in the test or just let it fail. Trying to convert exceptions to booleans only increases the complexity.

Answer (score 3):

First, [don't extend `TestCase`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started) - instead, use JUnit 4.x.

Second, I take great umbrage against a method with side effects.  There's no reason to modify your `save` method to return a `boolean` instead of `void`; you just have to take an alternative approach to testing the method.

Third, I'm of the persuasion that a simple unit test won't be able to cover the save functionality of this method. Something that reads like it would be persisted someplace is better suited for an integration test of some kind (using the database, ensuring that the file exists and the contents are correct, etc).

The main question you want to answer when you're unit testing is, "What is the expected result of this method invocation given this parameter?"  When we call `save`, what do we expect to happen?  Do we write to a database?  Do we serialize the contents and write to a file?  Do we write XML/JSON/plain text out?  That would have to be answered first, and *then* could a useful test be written around it.

The same thing applies for `read` - what do I expect to receive as input when I attempt to read a bill?  What do I gain from passing in a `Bill` object, and returning a `Bill` object?  (Why would an outside caller have a notion of a bill that I'm trying to read?)

You have to flesh out your expectations for these methods.  Here's an approach I use to write unit tests:

- **Given** a specific input,
- **when** I call this method,
- **then** I expect these things to be true.

You have to **define your expectations** before you can write the unit tests.

Comment: Wow, thanks man. Probably the most concise tutorial I have seen on unit testing. I have saved your answer in Evernote for easy reference

Answer (score 0):

Generally, implementation of read() and store() involves integrating with external system such as database, file system. This makes the test go hand in hand with the external system.

```
@Test
public void insertsBillToDatabase() {
    //setup your database

    bill.store(aBill);

    //fetch the inserted bill then assert
}
```

These tests are focused on whether you component is making an correct abstration on the external system.

Tests depending on external system are expensive because they are relatively slow and difficult to setup/cleanup. You'd better seperate business conerns and integration concerns if there are some complex business logic in the store().

```
public void store(Bill bill) {
    //business logic
    billDao.save(bill); // delegate to an injected dao, you can replace it with a test double in test code
}

@Test
public void doesSthToBillBeforeSave() {
    //replace your billDao with a stub or mock

    bill.store(aBill);

    //assert the billDao stub / mock are correctly invoked
    //assert bill's state
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hippoom, for now I am using object serialization to save the bill objects and not ready yet to make database connection, but your explanation does make perfect sense and I will come back to reference it once I get to the point of DAO/DI